# JSON data is undefined but appears in console log

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I am accessing the following JSON data at:

http://veratech.co.nz/blog/?json=1

When I try to access the "url" property that sits within an array on line 4 of the code below, I get an undefined error. Even though it will appear in console.log (line 13) with console.log(val.attachments[0].url);.

Code below:

```
        $.each(data.posts, function(index, val){
        output += '<li>';
        output += '<a href="#blogpost" onclick = showPost(' + val.id + ')">';
        output += '<img src="' + val.attachments[0].url + '" alt="">';
        output += '<h3>' + val.title + '</h3>';
        //Here we shorten the paragraph to 60 characters. 
        var str = val.excerpt;
        var paraInfo = str.slice(0, 60);
        output += '<p>' + paraInfo + '</p>';
        //Closing off the the closing html tags
        output += '</a>';
        output += '</li>';
        console.log(val.attachments[0].url);
    });//Go through each post
```

Advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: JSON does not seem valid

Comment: Are you really sure it's the same value you see in the console, and not the one from the previous iteration? If you get an error it'll stop the script execution and it won't reach the console.log line anymore.

Comment: It works as it should in the console and lists all the url data. As it should with the <img tag call on line 4. But ...... undefined.

Comment: Uh, which line exactly shows the error and what does it say specifically?

Comment: TypeError: val.attachments[0] is undefined

Comment: But console.log produces:  


http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/martial.jpg
custom.js (line 27)
http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/grave.jpg
custom.js (line 27)
http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/GTA5.jpg
custom.js (line 27)
http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/miyagi.jpg
etc...

Comment: Look, as I said, if you see that output **and** the error message, it means that the values you see are from **previous iterations**. Once you hit a post that doesn't have any attachments it throws an error.

Comment: Try to comment out line 4 and you'll see that it's now the console.log call that'll throw the error.

Comment: So What do I do to fix it. Does it need to exit out of the loop?And why does this not happen on the other JSON data like val.title?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something else wrong.

I downloaded the json manually, and wrote this code:

HTML:

```
Urls:
<ul id="foo">
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
function extractUrls(data) {
    var $foo = $('#foo');

    $.each(data.posts, function (i, p) {
        $foo.append($('<li></li>').text(p.attachments[0].url));
    });
}

var jsonData = { /* code omitted for brevity */ };

extractUrls(jsonData);
```

My output was:

```
Urls:
<ul id="foo">
    <li>http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/martial.jpg</li>
    <li>http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/grave.jpg</li>   
    <li>http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/GTA5.jpg</li>
    <li>http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/miyagi.jpg</li>
    <li>http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/htc-box.png</li>
    <li>http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/scaffold1.jpg</li>
    <li>http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/barriera.png</li>
    <li>http://veratech.co.nz/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/tv.jpg</li>
</ul>
```

Note: You should be able to replace the `var jsonData =` line with:

```
$.get('http://veratech.co.nz/blog/', { json: 1 }, extractUrls, 'json');
```

Anyway; can't see what's wrong with your code?  Are you sure this is the issue?

PS: I even added the following inside the `$.each` loop:

```
    if (!p.attachments[0].url) {
        alert(p.id + ' has undefined url!');
    }
```

And did not see any alert...

[See code running in a jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6y51othy/)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will test along those lines. Your more on planet earth than the other responses. Cheers

Comment: You may also wish to check for whether or not p.attachments has any values in the array, and whether or not an attachment has a url.  `if (p.attachments && p.attachments.length > 0 && p.attachments[0].url) { ... }`

Comment: @lowfi2dev Actually; just modified the [jsFiddle I posted with this update](http://jsfiddle.net/6y51othy/1/); note that some of your articles have no attachments with urls.